# How to print several lines into a graph with info from three files with ggplots in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying plots several lines into a graph. My info is in three csv. files with two columns for each one 'tiempo' and 'costo':

Example a .csv file:

```
tiempo;costo
0;0
1;0
2;0
3;0
4;0
5;0
...
```

I builded an scripts and I gets good results but in three differents graphs:

```
library(ggplot2)    
library(reshape2)
library(ggpubr)    

A <- read.csv(file='m-r1-g.csv',TRUE,";")
B <- read.csv(file='m-r1-w.csv',TRUE,";")
C <- read.csv(file='m-r1-h.csv',TRUE,";")

i <- ggplot(A, aes(x = tiempo, y = costo)) + geom_line(aes(colour = costo))
j <- ggplot(B, aes(x = tiempo, y = costo)) + geom_line(aes(colour = costo))
k <- ggplot(C, aes(x = tiempo, y = costo)) + geom_line(aes(colour = costo))

ggarrange(i, j, k + rremove("x.text"), 
          labels = c("A", "B", "C"),
          ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
```

How do I can join these lines into a graphs with differents lines color?

thanks.

Comment: I think this is probably already answered somewhere but you could add a column to each df that says if its A, B or C then use `rbind` to combine the dataframes and then use ggplot on the combined dataframe but with colour = your new column's name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution - I created simple data frames as I don't have your csvs

```
set.seed(123)
A <- data.frame(tiempo = seq(1,8), costo = rep(0,8))
B <- data.frame(tiempo = seq(1,8), costo = sample(seq(1,20),8))
C <- data.frame(tiempo = seq(1,8), costo = sample(seq(1,20),8))
```

Make into one data frame - could do with other methods
but this is nice because it adds a column to id the original frames

```
df <- bind_rows(list(A = A, B = B, C = C), .id = "id")
```

Here is the simple ggplot

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = tiempo, y = costo, color = id)) + geom_line()
```

[image]